# multilang with babel problem

Tags: languages, babel, cyrillic

I've loaded babel in my `.sty` file like this:

```
\RequirePackage[ukrainian,russian,english]{babel}
```

Then at `.tex` or at the same `.sty` file I am trying to:

```
\selectlanguage(X)
\languagename
\iflanguage{english}{eng}{}
\iflanguage{russian}{rus}{}
\iflanguage{ukrainian}{ukr}{}
```

And the result is:

```
X=>output
russian => rus (\languagename says russian)  OK!
ukrainian => rus (!!!) (languagename says ukrainian) WRONG!
english => eng (\languagename says english) OK!
```

What a magic it is?
Note: everything else like word "Content", "Chapter" and so on are correctly translates to specified language.

Comment: Please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug in `babel`, which appears when *two* cyrillic languages are chosen. I wrote about it in an [article published in number 9 of ArsTeXnica](http://www.guitex.org/home/images/ArsTeXnica/AT009/l%27arte%20esoterica%20di%20scrivere%20in%20cirillico%20con%20LATEX.pdf), the journal of GuIT, the Italian TeX users group.

You can get around the bug by correcting the behaviour of `babel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian,russian,english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@cyrillictext}{% 
  \fontencoding\cyrillicencoding 
  \selectfont 
  \let\encodingdefault\cyrillicencoding 
} 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyrillictext}{%
  \@cyrillictext} 
\let\cyr\cyrillictext 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Bulgarian}{% 
  \@cyrillictext 
  \foreign@language{bulgarian}} 
\let\Bul\Bulgarian \let\Bg\Bulgarian 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Russian}{% 
  \@cyrillictext 
  \foreign@language{russian}} 
\let\Rus\Russian 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Ukrainian}{% 
  \@cyrillictext 
  \foreign@language{ukrainian}} 
\let\Ukr\Ukrainian 
\AtBeginDocument{ 
  \@ifundefined{defaultcyrlanguage} 
    {\let\defaultcyrlanguage\bbl@main@language}
    {}
}
\renewcommand{\textcyrillic}[2][\defaultcyrlanguage]{%
  \expandafter\foreignlanguage\expandafter{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\languagename --\the\language --%
\iflanguage{english}{eng}{}%
\iflanguage{russian}{rus}{}%
\iflanguage{ukrainian}{ukr}{}

\selectlanguage{ukrainian}
\languagename --\the\language --%
\iflanguage{english}{eng}{}%
\iflanguage{russian}{rus}{}%
\iflanguage{ukrainian}{ukr}{}%

\selectlanguage{russian}
\languagename --\the\language --%
\iflanguage{english}{eng}{}%
\iflanguage{russian}{rus}{}%
\iflanguage{ukrainian}{ukr}{}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

With this code the declaration `\Russian` and `\Ukrainian` don't change the fixed words (they behave like the `otherlanguage*` environment); if you prefer to have the (IMO wrong) behavior of `babel`, change the occurrences of `\foreign@language` into `\select@language`.

---

The problem is that at loading time, each language defines `\cyrillictext` to use that language; so the last language loaded wins. When `\selectlanguage` or a similar command to select a cyrillic language is issued, `\cyrillictext` is executed as part of `\extras<language>`; so the language name is set correctly, but the language number is set instead to the cyrillic language last loaded in with `babel`, in the example case to Russian.

Comment: Great article. If you I have found more bugs, please report them for them to get fixed.

Comment: @JavierBezos I've sent a bug report at LaTeX Project